# Generalizing the Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem: Large collections of integer tuples with equal sums of $0$th, ..., $m$th powers

Tags: number-theory

One reasonably well-known property of the Thue-Morse sequence is that it can be used to provide solutions to the [Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem) - for example, splitting the first eight nonnegative integers into evil and odious numbers, we get

$0^0+3^0+5^0+6^0=1^0+2^0+4^0+7^0$

$0^1+3^1+5^1+6^1=1^1+2^1+4^1+7^1$

$0^2+3^2+5^2+6^2=1^2+2^2+4^2+7^2$

If we increase $8$ in this example to $2^m$, we can get two sets of numbers whose $0$th, $1st$, ... $m$th powers are all equal to one another.

A natural generalization is to ask whether we can obtain this same kind of pattern with more than two sets of integers at once. More formally, we ask for which $k,m>0$ it is possible to have $k$ distinct multisets of nonnegative integers whose sum of $n$th powers are equal for each $n=0,1,\ldots,m$. As the Thue-Morse sequence shows, this can be done for all $m$ with $k=2$.

With $m=1$, it's trivial to see that all $k$ will work, but the case $(k,m)=(3,2)$ is already nonobvious; the smallest solution of (13, 11, 0), (15, 8, 1), and (16, 5, 3) takes some work to locate.

With $m=2$, the maximal $k$-value I have found is $16$, with the 3-tuples (412, 389, 0), (430, 369, 2), (440, 357, 4), (444, 352, 5), (464, 325, 12), (474, 310, 17), (485, 292, 24), (497, 270, 34), (500, 264, 37), (510, 242, 49), (517, 224, 60), (522, 209, 70), (529, 182, 90), (530, 177, 94), (532, 165, 104), and (534, 145, 122), all of which sum to $801$ and whose squares sum to $321065$.

I also have a solution to $k=3, m=3$: (22, 21, 4, 3), (24, 18, 7, 1), (25, 15, 10, 0).

As the only barrier to locating these solutions has been computational power thus far, I expect that solutions exist for all $k, m$, though this seems like a very difficult proposition to show; does anyone have pointers to existing work on this question? I was unable to locate any such problem in, e.g., [Wikipedia's list of problems relating to sums of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_powers), or listed generalizations of the Prouhet–Tarry–Escott problem.

I would also be curious to see larger $(k,m)$ tuples that solutions are located for, as I'm not sure my current algorithms are particularly efficient at finding solutions.

Comment: A good search term is "multigrade equations". A. Gloden wrote a book about them in the early 1940s, very hard to find copies now, in German and in French.

Comment: https://openlibrary.org/books/OL14146262M/Mehrgradige_Gleichungen

Comment: Have you taken up my suggestions, Raven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you ask is also call "Multigrade Chains".
You may see plenty of such solutions on my below website:
[Multigrade Chains](http://eslpower.org/chains.htm)

Example:

$ \\\ \ \ \  0^k+ 567^k+644^k+1778^k+1855^k+2422^k  \\ =  2^k+535^k+678^k+1744^k+1887^k+2420^k \\ =  7^k+490^k+728^k+1694^k+1932^k+2415^k \\ =  15^k+444^k+782^k+1640^k+1978^k+2407^k \\=  28^k+392^k+847^k+1575^k+2030^k+2394^k \\=  42^k+350^k+903^k+1519^k+2072^k+2380^k \\ =  62^k+303^k+970^k+1452^k+2119^k+2360^k \\=  70^k+287^k+994^k+1428^k+2135^k+2352^k \\=  95^k+244^k+1062^k+1360^k+2178^k+2327^k \\=  103^k+232^k+1082^k+1340^k+2190^k+2319^k \\=  119^k+210^k+1120^k+1302^k+2212^k+2303^k \\=  144^k+180^k+1175^k+1247^k+2242^k+2278^k \\\ \ \ \ \ (k=1,2,3,4,5) $

Recently, I also find such solutions of trigonometry

$ \ \ \ \ \sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{0 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{2 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{2 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{11}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{4 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{4 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{11}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{11}\right) $

$ =\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{22}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{7 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{7 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{9 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{9 \pi }{22}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{11 \pi }{22}\right) $

$ 
=\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{2 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{4 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{7 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{8 \pi }{33}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{10 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{11 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{13 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{14 \pi }{33}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{16 \pi }{33}\right) $

$=\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{5 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{7 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{9 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{11 \pi }{44}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{13 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{15 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{17 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{19 \pi }{44}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{21 \pi }{44}\right)$

$ =\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{\pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{4 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{6 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{9 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{11 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{14 \pi }{55}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{16 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{19 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{21 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{24 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{26 \pi }{55}\right) $

$ =\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{2 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{3 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{7 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{8 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{12 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{13 \pi }{55}\right)\\+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{17 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{18 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{22 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{23 \pi }{55}\right)+\sin ^{2 k}\left(\frac{27 \pi }{55}\right) $
$ \ \ \ \ \\ ......$
$ \ \ \ \ \ \\ (k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) $

For more result on this, please refer to my Notebooks

http://eslpower.org/Notebook.htm

Answer (score 1):

Mathematician, "Chen Shuwen" has givn solution

for, $m=4$ & is shown below.

$m=1,2,3,4$

$(401,521,641,881,911)^m=(431,461,701,821,941)^m$

The link to his web page's is given below:

```
      http://eslpower.org
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please notice that the above solution you mentioned in my web site is a PRIME solution.  401,521,641,881,911,431,461,701,821,941 are all primes.

Normally, finding a prime solution of the Prouhet-Tarry-Escott Problem is much difficult than finding a interger solution.